# If there's no contradiction, can I make a sentence like this?

Tags: numbers

Under the circumstance that I needed two cups, I found a bundle of 5 cups, and I say *Oh, finally I found 2 cups*. As you see, there's no contradiction in itself, so is it okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine.

What would you do in your native language? There are no special rules for English here.

Moreover "contradictions", "falsehoods" and "paradoxes" are valid English.  So it would be correct English to say "I found negative-three bowls" in this context (it just is a lie and nonsensical)

In normal English you can say "I found some cups". But who are speaking to?  Most people wouldn't *say* anything they just take the two cups they need without speaking.